# Network slow on ubuntu machine

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have lately changed my laptop from windows to Linux. Since then Internet connection from this laptop is extremely slow. It's taking forever to open web pages.

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04. How can I troubleshoot this network problem?

I tried this `sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 <<<"1"`
as I found in a different post on this forum but it didn't work.

---

Edit:
The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` :

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: As I see here, this is only because of wlan-card built-in this machine ?! Would it help then to take a screw-driver and build out this wlan-card and after rebooting then simply use the ethernet plug-in with a network cable ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chip ID BCM 4311, 4312, 4313, 4321, 4322, 4331, 4352, 4360, **43142**, 43224, 43225, 43227, 43228, and others as suggested by Broadcom.

> The propietary Broadcom STA Wireless driver is maintained upstream by Broadcom. As this driver is closed source, fixes in the driver itself may only be provided by Broadcom. **As a convenience, Ubuntu offers two versions of this driver**:
>
> The **bcmwl-kernel-source package** aims to offer a later version for a given release. Instructions for installation may be found later in this article.
>
> The **broadcom-sta package** aims to offer an earlier version for a given release. For further installation instructions, please see here.

*Source* :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is no a really good solution. The only driver that support this adapter `[14e4:4365]` is the `wl` driver that is already installed.

It is a proprietary Broadcom driver.

In some cases it is slow, but there is no better solution so far.

You can use an external usb wireless dongle or replace the internal wireless adapter in your laptop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Which wireless dongle is well supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: That is very hard to tell, because vendors rarely declare which chip is used in a dongle.